# Kibana - change a dropdown menu based on another dropdown menu

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am new to QA, and Elastic Search in particular.

I wanted to ask, if I could create a dropdown menu in Kibana (Elastic Search's web visulization UI), where there are types of projects. For each project, of course, there are build version.

What I want to do, is based on the choice of the project, modify the build versions so they are specific to that project. Is there any way to do this?

I've no code to share, as all I've done is send Json to the Elastic Search server I'm running on my own PC through docker.

I'd be very grateful if someone could show me an example (even a simple one, maybe people, and for each person, there's their children, for example), so I could understand how to approach this problem.